# python Tkinter occupy image equally to other widget

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have this code.

```
class App(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.attributes('-zoomed', True)
        self.root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.root.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

        f1 = Frame(self.root, bd=1, bg="green")
        f3 = Frame(self.root, bd=1, bg="blue")

        self.image = Image.open("default.png")
        self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)
        self.label = Label(image=self.photo)
        self.label.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")

        f1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        f3.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky="ew")

app = App()
app.root.mainloop()
```

and the output is 
[image]

How can I make image occupy equally to the left frame?

Comment: But the image is already equally positioned to the left (green) frame, so what is your problem?

Comment: the problem is I want the green width and the picture width the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before providing a solution, there are few remarks I would like to highlight:

1. You did not use the frame `f3`for anything. It is not even displayed when running your program. So I will simply ignore it in my solution below.
2. You set the attribute `-zoomed` for the main frame' `attributes`. I do not know which goal you are going to fulfill by using it. Anyway, there are many threads that state it is working only Windows and some Debian distributions like Ubuntu. I did not experience this problem though, however, as you can read on the first link I provide below, those arguments are platform specific. So for the sake of portability of your code, you may use  [`-fullscreen`](http://wiki.tcl.tk/9457)  instead. But here again, especially for your case, it will affect even the taskbar of your GUI which will not be displayed and thus you can not close your program by clicking on the close button. So in my solution I will rather use [`winfo_screenheight()`](http://nullege.com/codes/search/tkinter.Tk.winfo_screenheight) and [`winfo_screenwidth()`](http://nullege.com/codes/search/tkinter.Tk.winfo_screenheight) to set `self.root` to the size of the screen of your machine and call them inside the [`geometry()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm#Tkinter.Wm.geometry-method) method.

Let us divide your problem into smaller ones:

1. First problem you need to resolve is how to set the first frame `f1` and  `self.label` to equal widths?. This is done by simply setting the width option of each one of them to the half of the width of your screen: `width = self.root.winfo_screenwidth()/2`
2. Once this is done, you will need to resolve the second problem you clarified in your comment. For that, you will need to resize `self.image` to fit `self.label` size by applying [`resize()`](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm#tag-Image.Image.resize) method on the image, and pass to it the dimensions of the image which must be the ones of your label along with the constant [`PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS`](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/releasenotes/2.7.0.html).

## Full program

So here is the full program:

```
'''
Created on May 5, 2016

@author: billal begueradj
'''
import Tkinter as Tk
import PIL.Image
import PIL.ImageTk

class App(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk.Tk()       
        self.root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.root.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)        
        # Get width and height of the screen
        self.h= self.root.winfo_screenheight()
        self.w= self.root.winfo_screenwidth()
        # Set the GUI's dimensions to the screen size
        self.root.geometry(str(self.w) + "x" + str(self.h))
        # Set the  width of the frame 'f1' to the half of the screen width 
        self.f1 = Tk.Frame(self.root, bd=1, bg="green", width= self.w/2)
        self.f1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")        
        # Load the image
        self.image = PIL.Image.open("/home/Begueradj/mahomet_pedophile.jpg")       
        # Resize the image to fit self.label width 
        self.photo = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)
        self.label = Tk.Label(self.root, image=self.photo,  width= self.w/2)
        self.label.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")


# Launch the main program      
if __name__ == '__main__':
   app = App()
   app.root.mainloop()
```

## Demo

[image]

## Nota Bene

There is a little imprecision through your comment. It does not say weither you want the whole picture to appear of the same size as the frame `f1` or just its label in which it is appended (`self.label`). If this is what you want to do, then just ignore this line in the previous program:

```
self.image = self.image.resize((self.w/2, self.h), PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)
```

**Demo**

The output will then look like this (the image is simply positioned in the center of the label):

[image: ]]